# Поиск в графе java

Tags: java, алгоритм

Дан массив A длины (n+1), содержащий натуральные числа от 1 до n. Найти любой повторяющийся элемент за время O(n), не изменяя массив и не используя дополнительной памяти.

```
public static void main (String[] args){

    int[] array = {7, 5, 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 8, 4};

    newFind(array);
}
public static void newFind(int[] mas){
    int index = mas.length;
    int el = mas[index - 1];
    int object = mas[el - 1];
    while (true){

        object = mas[el - 1];
        el = mas[object - 1];
        el = mas[el - 1];
        el = mas[el - 1];

        if (object == el) {
            System.out.println(el);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Я реализовал это так, но если цикл будет иметь больше или меньше шагов, то программа сломается. Моя проблема в том, что я не пойму как считать длину цикла до повторяющегося элемента и вывести элемент на экран. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: что на счет увеличения `i` в самом конце?

Comment: Что понимается под дополнительной памятью? Ещё одна переменная это дополнительная память?

Comment: @Эникейщик, ограничение на использование дополнительной памяти означает, что нельзя заводить дополнительный массив линейной длины, но можно заводить переменные.

Comment: Свой ответ удаляю, но на будущее - ставьте **правильно** задание. Я точно ответил на ваш вопрос: **Моя проблема в том, что я не пойму как считать длину цикла**. После этого вы вдруг пишете - **мне ненужно считать количество всех действий. Мне требуется в определенный момент понять что я уже был в этом элементе и вывести его**. При невнятном ТЗ результат один - ХЗ.

Comment: Да, возможно я пишу медленнее чем думаю, извините. Буду стараться писать вопрос точнее. Ошибки не нашел, не подскажете где она?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще одна попытка помочь... :)
Простите, что не на Java, но, думаю, что вы сможете перевести. На C++ нужное вам решение имеет примерно следующий вид (понятно, что это не единственный способ... но мне было проще написать решение с нуля):

```
int Double(int * A, int N /*длина массива*/)
{
    int p = N, q = N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) p = A[p-1];
    int k = 1, s = p;
    while((p=A[p-1]) != s) ++k;
    p = N;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i) p = A[p-1];
    for(;p != q;)
    {
        p = A[p-1];
        q = A[q-1];
    }
    return p;
}
```

Думаю, что на Java это будет выглядеть как

```
public static void newFind(int[] A)
{
    int N = mas.length;
    int p = N, q = N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) p = A[p-1];
    int k = 1, s = p;
    while((p=A[p-1]) != s) ++k;
    p = N;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; ++i) p = A[p-1];
    for(;p != q;)
    {
        p = A[p-1];
        q = A[q-1];
    }
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

:)

Работает за O(N), лишней памяти не просит...

Comment: Тут нужно даже два счетчика, но ваш, ответ не подходит по заданию, т.к. мне ненужно считать количество всех действий. Мне требуется в определенный момент понять что я уже был в этом элементе и вывести его.

Comment: для графа есть такая пометка: `boolean wasVisited`. `True` - если посетили

Comment: Ставьте **правильно** задание. Я ответил на ваш вопрос: **Моя проблема в том, что я не пойму как считать длину цикла** Кстати, у вас в теле цикла ошибка...

Comment: Да так работает, но на сколько я помню О(n) означает, что алгоритм должен сделать не более n шагов по массиву. А здесь он уже в первом цикле делает n шагов по массиву. Возможно я заблуждаюсь в том, что думаю что шаг в данном случае это взятие элемента из массива, т.е. когда мы берем элемент который уже брали это новый шаг, не так ли?

Comment: Не более const*n шагов. 1000000000N шагов - это все равно O(N).